# There goes gravity

Tags: vocabulary

I was listening to this amazing song by Eminem : "lose yourself"

> Snap back to reality, ope there goes gravity
> Ope, there goes Rabbit

snap back means go back to reality but what does "there goes" mean here?

I actually thought there goes meant to lost sth so in that case there would be a contradiction here  If you lose gravity, then you've not snapped back to reality

and I know Rabbit is the nickname of Eminem but i can't get this sentence neither
So can someone explain this thanks in advance?

Comment: This is lyric interpretation.  Your understanding of the meaning of the English is correct.  I won't speculate on how we should interpret the meaning of the lyric as a piece of art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There goes" could be used both as a statement that (1) something is lost, and as a statement that (2) something is being introduced. For example (2):

> There goes the bell!

means that the bell is being introduced to the setting and performs an action (implicitly: it rings). Another example of the (2) meaning could be:

> And there she goes, being an absolute nuisance to us all.

which means that she gets introduced to the scene (walks in, etc.) and starts performing an action.

The meaning used in the lyrics about gravity is the second (2).